# MIPS and embedded systems

Tags: embedded, mips

Why is MIPS usually used on embedded systems? Is it because most embedded systems use RISC? Why would they prefer RISC over CISC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MIPS is not used much outside embedded systems, because the implementations are quite slow compared to x86 or ARM. On the other hand, plenty of embedded systems use some other processor than MIPS, there are a lot of alternatives.

RISC takes less silicon space to implement than CISC. Therefore the processors are cheaper and often also use less power, both of which are very desired properties in embedded systems.

Comment: "MIPS is not used much outside small embedded systems" That is absolutely not true. There are some extremely powerful MIPS processors used in "big iron" networking equipment.

Comment: Ok, well, embedded nevertheless; I'll edit the "small" out because you are right that it doesn't apply :)